# How to use the distanceTo command in R leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

Is there a way I can use the distanceTo command in R? I just see the javascript documentation? I already have the longitude and latitude.

Here's the command I'm talking about:
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-distanceto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `distHaversine()` function in the package `geosphere` to get the same result.
For example:

```
library(geosphere)

# Longitude and Latitude, respectively:
coords1 <- c(-71, 42)
coords2 <- c(-70, 41)

distance <- distHaversine(coords1, coords2)
```

This gives the great circle distance in meters:

```
R> distance
[1] 139077.2
```

Other distance functions in the same package such as `distVincentyEllipsoid()` might be more accurate but more computationally intensive.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what i needed. Thanks.